# How to concatenate a list with another list?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm not sure if I've described my problem accurately.
My problem is that I have this LazyColumn:

```
 LazyColumn {
        items(state.matches) {match->
                MatchItem(
                    match = match,
                    vm = vm
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

In above lines I'm fetching data from API. In this case I'm getting a list of Match, it contains some information about some soccer matches.

So the problem is that I want the user to predict the result of each match.

```
@Composable
fun ResultText(
    showText: Boolean,
    result: ResultState,
    onResultChanged: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    if (showText) {
        Text(text = result, fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.fontSize)
    } else {
        ResultPicker(onResultChanged = onResultChanged)
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to add the prediction in every single match because it is seperated from the data which I'm fetching. Is there's a way do that?

EDIT:

MatchItem composable:

```
@Composable
fun MatchItem(
    match: Match,
    result: ResultState,
    vm: HomeViewModel
) {
            Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(12.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
        ) {

            TeamInfo(
                team = match.team1,
                painter = flag1,
                horizontal = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                vertical = Arrangement.Top
            )


            ResultText(
                showText = (textOrPicker == ShowTextOrPicker.TEXT),
                result = result.team1,
                onResultChanged = {
                    vm.changeResult(result  = ResultState(
                        team1 = it.toString(),
                        team2 = result.team2
                    )
                    )
                }
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp),
                text = "VS",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )

            TeamInfo(
                team = match.team2,
                painter = flag2,
                horizontal = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                vertical = Arrangement.Bottom
            )

               ResultText(
                showText = (textOrPicker == ShowTextOrPicker.TEXT),
                result = result.team2,
                onResultChanged = {
                    vm.changeResult(result  = ResultState(
                        team1 = result.team2,
                        team2 = it.toString()
                    )
                    )
                }
            )
}

ResultState:

    data class ResultState(
    val team1:String = "-",
    val team2:String = "-"
)
```

And in viewmodel:

```
    private val _resultState =
 mutableStateOf<List<ResultState>>(emptyList())
    val resultState = _resultState
```

Comment: Is the `ResultText` composable used inside the `MatchItem` composable?
Can you show us how do you obtain the prediction data (and where it is related to your state.matches)?

Comment: Yes ResutText is just a function that decides if it should show the ResultPicker or the result text. For the prediction data I was taking it from ResultPicker function and then when the value changes I was adding it to a mutableStateOf(String) variable in viewModel until I realized that it was a stupid idea and I should use mutableStateOf(List<String>) instead but I don't know how because as I said it's independent from state.matches which is data fetched from API, and not picked from the user.

Comment: All right, show me the code where you are calling `ResultText` composable inside your `MatchItem` so that I see what state are you generating. Can you please also post your `ResultState` class so that I can provide you with an example that will actually fit your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `List<ResultState>` to store predictions for matches, you could store them in a `Map<Any, ResultState>`. The key could be the match id (if you have one) or you could make a key from some parameters that uniquely identify a match. You can use a `Pair` to create a key from 2 parameters or a `Triple` to create a key from 3 parameters. If you would need more than 3 parameters to create a unique key, then you can use a `data class` to represent your key or hash the parameters yourself to get the value for the key.

So the state would change to a `Map<Any, ResultState>` and `changeResult` would change to also accept a `key` as a parameter

```kotlin
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var resultState: Map<Any, ResultState> by mutableStateOf(emptyMap())
        private set

    fun changeResult(key: Any, result: ResultState) {
        resultState = resultState.plus(Pair(key, result))
    }
}
```

Then in your `MatchItem` you retrieve the `ResultState` using the key and also pass the key into the `vm.changeResult` calls.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MatchItem(
    match: Match,
    vm: HomeViewModel
) {
    // if your Match data has any unique identifier use it as the key
    // val key = match.id
    // otherwise, just use a Pair/Triple of parameters that create something unique
    val key = Pair(match.team1, match.team2)
    val result = vm.resultState[key] ?: ResultState()

    // ...
    
    ResultText(
        showText = (textOrPicker == ShowTextOrPicker.TEXT),
        result = result.team1,
        onResultChanged = {
            vm.changeResult(
                // add the key to the changeResult call
                key = key,
                result = ResultState(
                    team1 = it.toString(),
                    team2 = result.team2
                )
            )
        }
    )
    
    // ...

    ResultText(
        showText = (textOrPicker == ShowTextOrPicker.TEXT),
        result = result.team2,
        onResultChanged = {
            vm.changeResult(
                // add the key to the changeResult call
                key = key,
                result = ResultState(
                    team1 = result.team1,
                    team2 = it.toString()
                )
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Than you very much, you are a lifesaver!